# Understanding Django's server console output

Tags: django, http, appserver

I need help understanding what the final characters in django's development server output mean. Example:

> [04/Jan/2011 12:24:16] "GET /polls/
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 216

What does 216 stand for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Size of response. In bytes I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gruszczy. Do you recommend any reference link? I can't find any. Not even from inspecting django's code at /django/core/servers/basehttp.py, line code [quote] msg = "[%s] %s\n" % (self.log_date_time_string(), format % args)[/quote]

Comment: Nope, I am just guessing from experience. I tried looking into both python and django code, but couldn't find it easily. Test it out (try returning strings of different size and see, if this match).

Comment: Guessing right. Refer to this answer for code level details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635140/django-development-server-messages-what-do-they-mean?rq=1