# Django development server messages - what do they mean?

Tags: django, message

If I run a Django development server and view my application in a browser, I get messages like this:

> [08/Jan/2011 18:12:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2714
>
> [08/Jan/2011 18:12:45] "GET /static/style.css" 200 2714
>
> [08/Jan/2011 18:12:45] "GET /content.html" 200 269
>
> ...

What does the last number on each line mean?
(I know that the number one before last is standard HTTP status message, but don't know what the following number represents)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the number of bytes sent, see [django/core/servers/basehttp.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L452):

```
self.request_handler.log_request(self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent)
```